# Making telegram's AppBar with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-appbar

I am trying to make an app bar exactly like what you see here

[image]

However as I'm new to flutter I do not have any idea how I can make it, I already tried `MainCollapsingToolbar` but it didn't get me anywhere. Does anyone have any idea if can I make it?

Comment: take a look at SliverAppbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with a simple 'Silver Bar', then you can customize it for your own use.

This is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AppBarApp());

class AppBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SliverAppBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class SliverAppBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverAppBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverAppBarExample> createState() => _SliverAppBarExampleState();
}

class _SliverAppBarExampleState extends State<SliverAppBarExample> {
  bool _pinned = true;
  bool _snap = false;
  bool _floating = false;

// [SliverAppBar]s are typically used in [CustomScrollView.slivers], which in
// turn can be placed in a [Scaffold.body].
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: _pinned,
            snap: _snap,
            floating: _floating,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
              background: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Scroll to see the SliverAppBar in effect.'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: OverflowBar(
            overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('pinned'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _pinned = val;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _pinned,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('snap'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _snap = val;
                        // Snapping only applies when the app bar is floating.
                        _floating = _floating || _snap;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _snap,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('floating'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _floating = val;
                        _snap = _snap && _floating;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _floating,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find more examples by searching with the keyword 'Silver Bar'.

Answer (score 2):

you can use SliverAppBar, [this](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe) can help you

Comment: links of answers are not valid answers. Please write a detailed answer to explain how it works and references to support them